# Creating array of byte/char of unknown length?

Tags: c++

If I have a char array of say 3000 characters which represents say 20 lines in a file (but the lines are different lengths) how could I "insert" each line in to a char array of the "correct" appropriate size? Is this impossible to do- or I would just need to use a vector rather than a raw C-style array?

Comment: why would you want to use arrays over vectors?

Comment: A `std::vector<std::string>` should easily do what you want. Unless you want to pass a single-buffer to some external api expecting it all in one big block of goo.

Comment: I think your mistake is trying to use a one dimensional data structure. A sequence of lines which each line being a sequence of characters is a two dimensional data structure. std::vector<std::string> is the obvious choice.

Comment: Not a vector<char>? My input is a char array...

Comment: @user997112 your read the lines from the file character by character?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a std::string array[20] you will have to include "string" though.

Comment: `<string>`, to be specific.